# Hotel Availability search utilising geo codes and a radius

Tags: sabre

We are using the `OTA_HotelAvailLLSRQ` action (https://developer.sabre.com/docs/read/soap_apis/hotel/search/hotel_availability/resources)

and want to do a purely location based search using latitude and longitude. All fine except we cannot use a radius to narrow down the search results. We also cannot seem to order by distance from point.

The search results seem to be returned in a random order.

Is there any way to narrow down the search radius as if searching in the center of London or Manhattan, for instance, hotels 20 miles away are clearly inappropriate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `DistanceDirection` and `Sort` to change the radius and order of the results respectively.

```
<RefPoint DistanceDirection="5" Sort="true"/>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Tested this and confirm it works - thank you so much! You don't happen to know how Sabre calculates "distance from point" do you? As when I do a test based on a haversine of the Hotel geocode and the search geocode occasionally they are slightly out of order?